# What to do to dismiss a dialog box which is coded as a dialog activity?

Tags: android

```
/*packages and imports*/

public class BookmarkDialoge extends Activity 
{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bookmarksaver);
}

public void bookmarking(View v)
{
EditText bookmarking=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.bookmarkname);
final String bookMarkname=bookmarking.getText().toString();
String pathdir= getIntent().getExtras().getString("bookpath");
String address=getIntent().getExtras().getString("chapterAddress");
System.out.println("book directory in bookmark class is "+ pathdir);

SQLiteDatabase db;
            db=openOrCreateDatabase("epub.db",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);
            db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
            db.setLockingEnabled(true);
            db.setVersion(1);
    try
    {
        String updateQuery1 = "UPDATE BookMark SET addresname=? WHERE bookdir=? AND lastaddress=?";
                    db.execSQL(updateQuery1, new String[] { bookMarkname, pathdir,address });
                    System.out.println("Bookmark table updated with name");   
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
        }
        finally
        {
        db.close();
        }


}

}
```

and in manifest i have given this activity as

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog" >
```

sothat it appears as a dialoge

This is my class everything works well, but i need to dismiss the dialogebox after clicking the button, means it should just disappear, (it came as a popup box)
what should i do? please help

Comment: `finish()` the Activity in close button click

Comment: thanks it solved, such a small mistake from me!, sorry i am new in android.

Comment: @SimplePlan: Update your comment as a answer so that others will know it got a accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just `finish()` the `Activity` in close button `onClick()` event